# d3js chart: how to use clip-path to limit the length of a line to specific bounding box

Tags: javascript, css, charts, d3.js

My chart features a tooltip which has cross-hairs on hover.  These cross hairs are simple two lines (one vertical, one horizontal).

GOAL: limit the length of these lines such that they are contained within the graph area (gray 'grid plot' see line 220 for relevant snippet below.

Link to example: http://tributary.io/inlet/8361294

As you can see they span the entire width & height of the svg area, despite my best efforts to trim them down to the grid plot area by adding clip path. Code snippet:

```
/*
causes truncated lines on half viewport 

   focus.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);
*/

    // horizontal crosshair 
    focus.append("line")
          .attr({
            "x1": -width,
            "y1": 0,
            "x2": width,
            "y2": 0,
            "clip-path": "url(#clip)"
          });

    // vertical crosshair    
    focus.append("line")
            .attr({
              "x1": 0,
              "y1": -height,
              "x2": 0,
              "y2": height, 
              "clip-path": "url(#clip)"
            });
```

If you uncomment the "defs" snippet you'll see the odd behaviour.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easier to set the length of the crosshair lines explicitly rather than using a clip path:

```
focus.select(".h").attr(
  {"x1": margin.left - d3.mouse(this)[0],
   "x2": width - margin.right - d3.mouse(this)[0]});
focus.select(".v").attr(
  {"y1": margin.top - d3.mouse(this)[1],
   "y2": height - margin.bottom - d3.mouse(this)[1]});
```

This requires you to assign a class to each line so you can distinguish them. Complete example [here](http://tributary.io/inlet/8705447).